# Need MySQL Query to Chop String and add Serial Number (letter) to End, Where Duplicates

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have some 10 character skus like this:

AB1234ZYXW

AB1234ZYXN

AB1234ZYXP

AB1234ZYXR

ZZ1234ZYXR

But we need them to be 8 characters. Chopping them at 8 would make them non unique (except the last one).

The non-unique ones would all look like : AB1234ZY

So my solution is to chop one more character off of all them, giving AB1234Z, then adding a serial number (actually serial letter).  AB1234ZA, AB1234ZB, ...C ...D.

My first thought was to query the DB and do all the processing in PHP arrays, then send queries back to update. But since there can be 30,000 to process at a time, this will result in 30,000 UPDATE queries (one for each chopped sku anyway).

If it could be done with a single MySQL statement it would be much faster.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
To add more detail:

Total number of records could be 2,000 - 35,000 per batch. With the chopping, it will create groups of duplicates. If each group has less than 26 members, then 1 digit of serialization is enough. Otherwise 2 digits (26 x 26 = 676 and it's very unlikely a group would be larger than that). Ideally, the query would take into account the number of duplicates in each group and apply 1 or 2 digits of serialization depending. I know it's a lot to ask. jonstjohn's answer looks like a good start. I will test it tomorrow. I haven't used mysql variables for anything yet but it looks promising.

Comment: Is it a one off job? if so i would just use php. It will only take a few minutes on most machines.

Comment: It's for an application that will need to be used occasionally to fit long skus into a system that only accepts a certain number of characters. It will probably need to process 200,000 skus a couple of times per year and occasional smaller updates.  I think I already know how I'll do it in PHP but I wanted to see if there was a way to avoid sending an UPDATE for every single value.

Comment: I think you can use something like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916789/mysql-nested-select-in-update-of-same-table

All you have to do is chop the string and use a GROUP BY, but I'm not certain about the new letter you'd like to add. And what if you'll have more than A to Z records? Is that possible in your DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SET @num = 64;
UPDATE skus SET sku = concat(left(sku, 7),
    char(if((@num := @num + 1) <= 90, @num, @num := 65)));
```

Here's the explanation.

The first line assigns the integer 64 to the mysql variable @num.  The character code for 'A' is 65 and 'Z' is 90, so we assign one before the 'A' since it will be incremented in the update query.

The update query then updates each row of the skus table using the first 7 characters of the sku, plus an incrementing character (A-Z) using the @num variable.  When it hits 'Z', it resets itselft to 65 (and uses that value for that row).

It should be very fast and efficient.